# can implement GoogleCredential.FromFile(file.json) when debugging but not after publishing

Tags: c#, path, google-analytics-api

I'm trying to get data from Google Analytics through Data API v1Beta and it works properly until I publish the project(web application). Everything works fine except for the following code which is reading the json file downloaded from `console.cloud.Google.com`.

```
string credentialsPath = @"F:\programming\exercises\templates\Projects\Market\Market\assets\task\pageviewsaccess-36c9107b9047.json";
GoogleCredential credential = GoogleCredential.FromFile(credentialsPath);
```

I'm quite sure that the problem is finding or reading this file from that line after publishing the project while it works when debugging in Visual Studio.
I'd be thankful if you could help me.Am I supposed to change the way it finds the file or completely use another way to get data from Google Analytics?
Here is my code:

```
 // Google Analytics 4 property ID.
string propertyId = "414010928";

// Credential Path
string credentialsPath = @"F:\programming\exercises\templates\Projects\Market\Market\assets\task\pageviewsaccess-36c9107b9047.json";

GoogleCredential credential = GoogleCredential.FromFile(credentialsPath);
              
var client = new BetaAnalyticsDataClientBuilder
{
    CredentialsPath = credentialsPath
}.Build();

var dimensionfilter = new FilterExpression()
{
    Filter = new Google.Analytics.Data.V1Beta.Filter()
    {
        FieldName = "pageTitle",
        StringFilter = new Google.Analytics.Data.V1Beta.Filter.Types.StringFilter()
        {
            CaseSensitive = false,
            MatchType = Google.Analytics.Data.V1Beta.Filter.Types.StringFilter.Types.MatchType.Contains,
            Value = "code"
        }
    }
};
                
// Initialize request argument(s)
RunReportRequest request = new RunReportRequest
{
    Property = "properties/" + propertyId,
    Dimensions = { new Dimension { Name = "pageTitle" } },
    Metrics = { new Metric { Name = "activeUsers" } },
    DateRanges = { new DateRange { StartDate = "yesterday", EndDate = "today" } },
    DimensionFilter = dimensionfilter
};

// Make the request
var response = client.RunReport(request);
```

I've searched a lot and none of the solutions to make the project find or read that json file helped me.
I have tried:

- setting properties of .json file to : Build Action:Content and Copy To Outboard Directory:Copy always
- also change the way to find the file like:

```
 string path = $"assets\\task\\pageviewsaccess-36c9107b9047.json";
                string AppPath = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase);
                AppPath = AppPath.Replace("file:\\", "");
                AppPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(AppPath, path);
                string read = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(AppPath);
```

- or

```
 string filepath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"assets\task\pageviewsaccess-36c9107b9047.json";
```